# How to inspect element using UIAUTOMATOR in android 9

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

**Environment** 
 1. ANDROID Version 9.0
 2. Android SDK tools version 25.2.5
 3. Application type Hybrid app
 4. Java version 1.8.0_181

**Issue**

Whenever I am trying to get the UI dump of my application using uiautomatorviewer its shows below error.

> Unexpected error while obtaining UI hierarchy
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I also observed that when I connect devices with android version 7,6 and 5 its working fine.

what is the best way to inspect elemets in android 8 and 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys after investigation I got a solution,
We can use Appium inspector for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly I think Appium Desktop consumes a lot of performance from our machine, so to avoid this performance loss I use "App Inspector": https://macacajs.github.io/app-inspector/

Using "App Inspector" you can inspect iOS/Android elements through the web.

[image]